# Tests throw exception saying user lacks privilege or object not found: REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY after update HSQLDB to 2.0.0

Tags: automated-tests, hsqldb, referential-integrity

Recently I upgraded my maven HSQL dependency to org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.0.0 from version 1.8.1.2. However all the tests that used HSQLDB failed, with an exception saying:

```
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY
```

I googled it and found a few answers but I found them hard to understand. How can I fix my tests? Before the upgrade my tests worked OK.

Answer (score 11):

This refers to the statement

```
SET REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY { TRUE | FALSE }
```

This statement has changed to

```
SET DATABASE REFERENTIAL INTEGRITY { TRUE | FALSE}
```

Once released on Maven, you should use HSQLDB 2.1 as this has bug fixes and better backward compatibility. In the meantime you can use the latest 2.1 RC4 or the jar snapshots from http://hsqldb.org/support/

Comment: Just found this answer.  I note that the most current edition (as of 05/2013) of the HTML user guide at http://hsqldb.org continues to describe the syntax of this option as SET REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY { TRUE | FALSE }